# Running a .bat script with multiple configurations

Tags: batch-file

I made a simple script to backup my databases, right now I'm having a problem, I store the variables of each server on a `.txt` and I'm trying to load them in the script multiple times.

Right now with this config it overwrites the configs instead of running it for each file.

Is there a way to make the script execute with file `xxx` then file `yyy` etc...

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (servers\xxx.txt servers\yyy.txt etc) do (
    %%a
)

:: Backup folder
set backupfldr="C:\Backup\files\"
:: MySQL EXE Path
set mysqldumpexe="C:\Backup\mysqldump-5_6.exe"
:: zip 
set zipper="C:\Backup\zip\7za.exe"

:: date
set datetimef=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
:: final
set bkupfilename=%datetimef%-%dbname%.sql


:: start
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%

%mysqldumpexe% --set-gtid-purged=OFF -h %server% -u %dbuser% -p%dbpass%  
%dbname% > %backupfldr%"%bkupfilename%"
```

.txt files are like this

```
set server=100.100.100.100
set dbname=nameofdatabase
set dbuser=userofdatabase
set dbpass=passofdatabase
```

Comment: would be nice to know, how `xxx.txt` etc. are formatted. Can you show one of those files (of course with obscured passwords...)?

Comment: yes I just set the variable on the .txt and then execute the rest of the script. right now since all files have the same variables, file 2 will overwrite file 1. And I'm looking to make the script run for file 1 then file 2, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not verify your logic, but for a list of strings (filenames here) use a plain `for` (without `/f`):

```
REM for every of those files call a subroutine:
for %%a in ("servers\xxx.txt" "servers\yyy.txt" etc) do call :process %%a
goto :eof

:process
copy "%~1" "%~dp0\temp.bat"
call "%~dp0\temp.bat"
:: Backup folder
set backupfldr="C:\Backup\files\"
:: MySQL EXE Path
set mysqldumpexe="C:\Backup\mysqldump-5_6.exe"
:: zip 
set zipper="C:\Backup\zip\7za.exe"

:: date
set datetimef=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
:: final
set bkupfilename=%datetimef%-%dbname%.sql

:: start
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%

%mysqldumpexe% --set-gtid-purged=OFF -h %server% -u %dbuser% -p%dbpass%  
%dbname% > %backupfldr%"%bkupfilename%"
```

(given, your .txt files look like:

```
set server=100.100.100.100
set dbname=nameofdatabase
set dbuser=userofdatabase
set dbpass=passofdatabase
```

)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly after adding the call subroutine.